# Trying to change Transparancy and Fill Color of KML's being rendered

Tags: swift, google-maps, kml

I am loading KML files onto the google map and would like to either have them completely transparent, except for the border colors, or have them be completely filled with the same color as the border.

I have tried manually editing the KML files tags to custom colors and adding the fill option. Only the outlines are changing color, and the background is still a blue tint.

```
    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "shapes", ofType: "kml")
    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path!)
    kmlParser = GMUKMLParser(url: url)

    print(String(kmlParser.placemarks.count))
    kmlParser.parse()

    print("KML Placemarks")

    renderer = GMUGeometryRenderer(map: mapView, geometries: kmlParser.placemarks, styles: kmlParser.styles)

    renderer.render()

<Style><LineStyle><color>ff102ae9</color></LineStyle><PolyStyle><fill>1</fill></PolyStyle></Style>
    <ExtendedData><SchemaData schemaUrl="#DVW_Poll_Shapes">
        <SimpleData name="OBJECTID">31213</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Shape_Leng">54.14420964730</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Shape_Area">150.01281437100</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="pd_id">1226974.00000000000</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="pd_num">414</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="pd_nbr_sfx">0</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="pd_type_co">S</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="pd_type">Single Building</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="adv_poll">605</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="ad_updt_dt">2014/01/09</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="fed_num">35021</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="ed_id">2168</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="a_updt_dte">2014/09/05</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="g_updt_dte">2013/12/18</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="emrp_name">414</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="poll_name">Toronto</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="urban_rura">U</SimpleData>
    </SchemaData></ExtendedData>
      <MultiGeometry><Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-79.3915075485372,43.7118790632914 -79.3914461229801,43.711708989583 -79.3915940654072,43.711771743595 -79.3916247891187,43.7118567782021 -79.3915075485372,43.7118790632914</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon></MultiGeometry>
  </Placemark>
  <Placemark>
    <Style><LineStyle><color>ff0000ff</color></LineStyle><PolyStyle><fill>0</fill></PolyStyle></Style>
    <ExtendedData><SchemaData schemaUrl="#DVW_Poll_Shapes">
        <SimpleData name="OBJECTID">31250</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Shape_Leng">4948.09285323000</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Shape_Area">276747.33755900001</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="pd_id">1226816.00000000000</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="pd_num">1</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="pd_nbr_sfx">0</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="pd_type_co">N</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="pd_type">Normal</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="adv_poll">601</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="ad_updt_dt">2014/01/09</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="fed_num">35021</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="ed_id">2168</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="a_updt_dte">2014/09/05</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="g_updt_dte">2014/02/03</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="emrp_name">1</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="poll_name">North York</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="urban_rura">U</SimpleData>
    </SchemaData></ExtendedData>
      <MultiGeometry><Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-79.3829339057042,43.7640197027211 -79.3824213046479,43.7642986089789 -79.3813317261181,43.7645308700421 -79.3805594887594,43.7646954866915 -79.3804171119731,43.7647245604304 -79.379734983861,43.7648637890067 -79.3795350883956,43.7649060063971 -79.3793457889739,43.7649417086907 -79.3783363016466,43.7651320956575 -79.3777372162075,43.765231696825 -79.3775375901914,43.765264804412 -79.3773379126225,43.7652980023781 -79.3771381895119,43.765331193887 -79.3767390943774,43.7653885907906 -79.3765394051902,43.7654216871224 -79.3763272943785,43.7654547133509 -79.3761278865625,43.7654789030921 -79.3760889253479,43.7654853790177 -79.375928194652,43.7655121050385 -79.3757287863783,43.7655362938797 -79.3755291006739,43.7655693893707 -79.3754610617286,43.7655770961034 -79.3753171864395,43.765593395406 -79.3751178096301,43.7656175959002 -79.3749184061964,43.7656418105093 -79.3747064997753,43.7656657906126 -79.3744947030105,43.765689812303 -79.374493976808,43.7656898878276 -79.3732490911899,43.7658070928031 -79.3730375056298,43.765822096344 -79.3728259082594,43.7658370978081 -79.3726142868677,43.7658520949762 -79.3724024165043,43.7658761024911 -79.3722032078521,43.7658913012494 -79.3719915856488,43.7659062979611 -79.3717799896258,43.7659211982494 -79.3715685947478,43.765927207415 -79.3702297465856,43.7659948874685 -79.3690680182758,43.7660535914155 -79.3657467052555,43.7662043099664 -79.3654605827209,43.7662181970813 -79.3654592298692,43.7662182609634 -79.3652250503774,43.7662289643845 -79.3629663912518,43.7663321367315 -79.3628468231125,43.7661767421519 -79.3627137529701,43.7660038146628 -79.3626782062289,43.7659575959947 -79.3626672118907,43.7659435834563 -79.3623867018644,43.7655866002722 -79.3622289937908,43.7652486863294 -79.362088212425,43.7648837111444 -79.3620177873659,43.7645041021951 -79.3619858090691,43.7640978124729 -79.3619989118321,43.7638130917912 -79.3619132898164,43.7620394959611 -79.3619110305792,43.7619912684916 -79.3619108806645,43.7619896068031 -79.3619086955509,43.7618252547234 -79.3619067807148,43.7616834083467 -79.3618663033079,43.7613496899886 -79.3618008083822,43.7610155972046 -79.3616615044584,43.7602032977596 -79.3616026175966,43.7600853948528 -79.3614682915072,43.7595433087774 -79.3612549990718,43.7587119052442 -79.3623790057887,43.7584938930712 -79.3624256877354,43.7586026007196 -79.36265809597,43.7591911947539 -79.3627298884738,43.7592912091407 -79.3628377110572,43.7594367940909 -79.3629945169627,43.7596101933 -79.3631032950465,43.7597197945769 -79.3632118940043,43.7598383888159 -79.3633329146342,43.7599571897155 -79.3634550850837,43.760030890587 -79.3635655899567,43.7600775012698 -79.3637384951319,43.7601160125493 -79.3638862971123,43.7601631913237 -79.3639837112292,43.7602365998524 -79.3640555061464,43.7603367123205 -79.3641031844641,43.7604093966706 -79.3641544092345,43.7605169929181 -79.3642423923734,43.7607714986148 -79.3642764074646,43.760889009065 -79.3643102920499,43.7610155923472 -79.3643436054062,43.7611601033211 -79.3643520924121,43.7613043037956 -79.3643354792104,43.7614571105593 -79.3643061863275,43.7616187831813 -79.3642771966803,43.7617713912838 -79.3642352968423,43.761941903898 -79.3641940996236,43.7620853985281 -79.3641539886755,43.7621928040051 -79.364138086485,43.7623187105335 -79.3641343930697,43.7624537040392 -79.3641449185196,43.7625257882023 -79.3641533902404,43.7626699974536 -79.3641496989964,43.7628049915821 -79.3641954023859,43.7629497056455 -79.3643010922039,43.7631763039167 -79.3647156010671,43.7639206006892 -79.3649176963182,43.7642566097044 -79.3651331056523,43.7645299094107 -79.3652168044102,43.7646751122874 -79.3653016006789,43.7647573043551 -79.3653987077968,43.7648397040476 -79.3654960986504,43.7649131072082 -79.3656064095428,43.7649687061634 -79.365729406974,43.7650155008561 -79.3658528103763,43.7650442997597 -79.3659765209433,43.7650640952741 -79.3661006824938,43.7650659009996 -79.3673316099707,43.7650294154583 -79.3682639800441,43.7650067078686 -79.3685866842761,43.7650202891457 -79.3689829009464,43.7650709925424 -79.369243890294,43.7650656908195 -79.3699956013944,43.765024999402 -79.3705252993868,43.7650029938172 -79.3712599087826,43.7649414029488 -79.3717199000536,43.7649300102016 -79.3727587108598,43.7648550016139 -79.3743303207882,43.7653362956924 -79.3744597482019,43.7653245576716 -79.3751024855465,43.7652662085369 -79.3761488007382,43.7651641002955 -79.3762734880773,43.7651478038524 -79.3764105911781,43.765131791118 -79.3771840101324,43.765016702381 -79.3775210028643,43.7649585021559 -79.377845409059,43.7649091094486 -79.3781699082671,43.7648505849098 -79.3784945151805,43.7647922089199 -79.3788189120015,43.7647427847969 -79.3791434817779,43.764684401085 -79.3791659387112,43.7646803690182 -79.3794680927748,43.7646259961632 -79.3797926857761,43.7645675072687 -79.3801172838148,43.7645090973709 -79.380442094143,43.7644416991472 -79.3825391032,43.7640752030626 -79.3829339057042,43.7640197027211</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon></MultiGeometry>
  </Placemark>
  <Placemark>
    <Style><LineStyle><color>ff3a96b0</color></LineStyle><PolyStyle><fill>1</fill></PolyStyle></Style>
    <ExtendedData><SchemaData schemaUrl="#DVW_Poll_Shapes">
        <SimpleData name="OBJECTID">31251</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Shape_Leng">844.55728490700</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Shape_Area">30974.40888300000</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="pd_id">1226899.00000000000</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="pd_num">71</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="pd_nbr_sfx">0</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="pd_type_co">N</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="pd_type">Normal</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="adv_poll">603</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="ad_updt_dt">2014/09/05</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="fed_num">35021</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="ed_id">2168</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="a_updt_dte">2014/10/10</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="g_updt_dte">2013/12/18</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="emrp_name">71</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="poll_name">North York</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="urban_rura">U</SimpleData>
    </SchemaData></ExtendedData>
      <MultiGeometry><Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-79.3718486070514,43.7180493115572 -79.3718260834591,43.7179493039593 -79.3740483026248,43.7175098691076 -79.375646922996,43.7171936938997 -79.3759407871753,43.717973590952 -79.3760049888245,43.7181341929831 -79.3745826589327,43.7183124432483 -79.3720637898542,43.7186054254925 -79.3718486070514,43.7180493115572</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon></MultiGeometry>
  </Placemark>
```

Comment: Can you share your KML file, or a representative sample?

Comment: @ChristiaanAdams Yes, its just basic polling data from a riding in Canada. Here is the data.

Comment: Did you provide a link?  If so, it didn't come through. Try again?

Comment: @ChristiaanAdams Head down to the packaged KMZ section (which unzips into KML) here is the link: https://open.canada.ca/data/en/dataset/737be5ea-27cf-48a3-91d6-e835f11834b0

Answer (score 2):

The file you shared in the comments looks like a relatively straight-forward KML, with a large collection of polygons, all of which share the same style.  In this case, the style they point to is a StyleMap, which in turn points to a normal style and a highlight style.  Unless you want the styling to change when the user hovers their mouse pointer on the feature, you should simply make the normal and highlight style be exactly the same.

The default styles in the file include only a polygon outline color, and no polygon fill. To add fill, you first need to add a `<fill>1</fill>` tag to the PolyStyle, and while you're at it, you might as well explicitly specify `<outline>1</outline>` as well. More documentation on PolyStyle is here: https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#polystyle

Next you need to edit the colors correctly. Note that KML colors are not like HTML colors (red,green,blue).  KML colors are reversed, and have the two-digit alpha (opacity) in front, so they read: AABBGGRR. For example, a 50% opaque orange would be `<color>8014B4FF</color>`, and the PolyStyle ends up looking like this:

```
<PolyStyle>
    <color>8014B4FF</color>
    <fill>1</fill>
    <outline>1</outline>
</PolyStyle>
```

A useful site for KML colors is: http://www.zonums.com/gmaps/kml_color/

Below is an example KML derived from your original. I replaced the polygons with one rectangle, removed all the attribute data (Schema and ExtendedData tags), and made the styling edits mentioned above. I also made the highlight styles a bit different, so you can see how that can work (outline gets bigger & yellow, fill gets less opaque). You can simply copy/paste it into Google Earth Pro to see the results. Hopefully that gets you what you need.

If you want to share what you tried to edit in the KML which didn't work, we can try to provide feedback on why.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
<Document>
    <name>Styling example</name>

    <StyleMap id="m_ylw-pushpin">
        <Pair>
            <key>normal</key>
            <styleUrl>#s_ylw-pushpin</styleUrl>
        </Pair>
        <Pair>
            <key>highlight</key>
            <styleUrl>#s_ylw-pushpin_hl</styleUrl>
        </Pair>
    </StyleMap>
    <Style id="s_ylw-pushpin">
        <LineStyle>
            <color>ff0000ff</color>
            <width>3</width>
        </LineStyle>
        <PolyStyle>
            <color>8014B4FF</color>
            <fill>1</fill>
            <outline>1</outline>
        </PolyStyle>
    </Style>
    <Style id="s_ylw-pushpin_hl">
        <LineStyle>
            <color>ff00ffff</color>
            <width>5</width>
        </LineStyle>
        <PolyStyle>
            <color>5014B4FF</color>
            <fill>1</fill>
            <outline>1</outline>
        </PolyStyle>
    </Style>

    <Placemark id="kml_1">
        <name>example polygon</name>
        <snippet></snippet>
        <description>This is the description (attribute data removed for this example).</description>
        <styleUrl>#m_ylw-pushpin</styleUrl>
        <Polygon>
            <outerBoundaryIs>
                <LinearRing>
                    <coordinates>
                        -79.6,43.8,0 
                        -79.6,43.7,0 
                        -79.5,43.7,0 
                        -79.5,43.8,0 
                        -79.6,43.8,0 
                    </coordinates>
                </LinearRing>
            </outerBoundaryIs>
        </Polygon>
    </Placemark>

</Document>
</kml>
```

Comment: I tried adding those in. But they only fill the lines with color, not the shapes. And furthermore, the light blue tint from Google Maps is still there. Is there any way I can breakdown each KML shape into its own polygon, and map them that way?

Comment: Please share the code you've tried, without which we can't help you debug.  Link to a copy of your file, if you can. Or if that's hard, at least start by pasting in the Styles sections which you edited. Also, I don't know what the "blue tint" is that you're referring to... maybe provide a screenshot?  Are you seeing the same issues when viewing the KML in Earth Pro, or is it different when viewed in Google Maps? If so, then you might be trying to use KML options which aren't supported in Maps.

Comment: I added a snippet of the KMLs I am working with, and what I have edited.

Comment: Thanks.  In the KML you shared, each style section has a <color> tag in the <LineStyle> (which defines color for the outline), but you have no <color> tags in the  <PolyStyle> (which is required to specify the color of the fill). See the Style section in my answer for an example of how to add color to the PolyStyle.